# Change string value

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to replace  `^` to `<span>`. But, I failed. I tried with `str_replace` but don't work properly.

So, my original value is:

```
^ffcb4a Special reward of the territory war. \rUsed to manufacture Rank IX gears. \rDon&#039;t lose this.
```

You can see, that have a color value, starts with `^` and I want to replace that for: `'<span style=color"#ffcb4a">`.

But with my `str_replace`, I got this:

```
<span style='color:#'ffcb4a Special reward of the territory war. \rUsed to manufacture Rank IX gears. \rDon&#039;t lose this.
```

As u can see, it doesn't work.

```php
$item_description = str_replace('^', "<span style='color:#'" . '', $item_description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a regex for this.

```
$item_description = '^ffcb4a Special reward of the territory war. \rUsed to manufacture Rank IX gears. \rDon\'t lose this.';
echo preg_replace('/\^(.*?)\h/', 
'<span style="color:#$1">', 
$item_description);
```

Output:

```
<span style="color:#ffcb4a">Special reward of the territory war. \rUsed to manufacture Rank IX gears. \rDon't lose this.
```

It also is unclear where you want the `span` to end..

This regex captures everything between a `^` and the first horizontal white space.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bA4dC8/1

You can't use the `str_replace` because you don't know where to close the `span`.

If you wanted to pull the first 6 characters after `^` you could change

```
(.*?)\h
```

to

```
(.{6})
```

Which says any 6 characters.

Example:

```
$item_description = '^ffcb4a Special reward of the territory war. \rUsed to manufacture Rank IX gears. \rDon\'t lose this.';
    echo preg_replace('/\^(.{6})/', 
    '<span style="color:#$1">', 
    $item_description);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very grateful. And, if my text be "merged" with color? Example: ^ffcb4aSpecial

Comment: You could pull the first 6 characters after the `^`. Will it always be 6 characters though..

Comment: Updated for that case as well.